# Change a String to Uppercase if it Exists - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How do I change a particular string to Uppercase only if it exists.

```
If (Cells(i, "A") Like "*roada*") Or (Cells(i, "A") Like "*roadb*") _
Or (Cells(i, "A") Like "*roadc*") etc... Then 'Change only the found string to Uppercase.
```

Each cell contains two or more words. Example: Cell A1 consists of "roadhouse blues". I want only 'roadh' to change to Uppercase if it exists in that cell. Is this possible in VBA?

Comment: Are you testing the entire alphabet in one `If` statement? Careful, that could easily end up on The Daily WTF...

Comment: @minitech Yes, I am. Yeah, I totally know that this is not the right method, but just wanted to know if this is possible if I had one condition.

Comment: you can use `Like "*road[a-z]*"`...quicker

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
Const road As String = "road"

Dim s As String
Dim letterAfterRoad As String

s = "play that roadhouse blues" ' or get contents of some cell
letterAfterRoad = Mid(s, InStr(s, road) + Len(road), 1)
Mid(s, InStr(s, road)) = UCase(road & letterAfterRoad)

Debug.Print s ' returns "play that ROADHouse blues". Write to cell.
```

---

If I were you, I would heed @minitech's sarcastic remark. If what you're looking for is `road?` where `?` is a letter `a-z` then let `Like` look for `a-z` rather than manually typing the entire alphabet...

Here is how I would do it:

```
Const road As String = "road"

Dim s As String
Dim charAfterRoad As String
Dim roadPos As Long

s = "play that roadhouse blues"

roadPos = InStr(s, road)
If roadPos > 0 And Len(s) >= roadPos + Len(road) Then
    'Found "road" and there is at least one char after it.
    charAfterRoad = Mid(s, roadPos + Len(road), 1)
    If charAfterRoad Like "[a-z]" Then
        Mid(s, InStr(s, road)) = UCase(road & charAfterRoad)
    End If
End If

Debug.Print s ' returns "play that ROADHouse blues"
```

Comment: +1. I especially like the Const for road.  It's too easy to change the string your searching for and forget to change the length of it.  I created a Prefix in my utility library to handle that type of search.

Comment: +1 For seeing something which I couldn't. i.e if the author actually means that which is yet unclear :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way. Let Excel do the dirty work ;)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim ReplaceString As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    '~~> Search String
    SearchString = "roadh"
    '~~> Replace string
    ReplaceString = UCase(SearchString)

    '~~> Change A1 to to the respective cell
    Set aCell = Range("A1").Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Range("A1").Replace What:=SearchString, Replacement:=ReplaceString, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Also instead of looping you might want to use .FIND/.FINDNEXT ?

**More on 'Find/FindNext'**: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

FIND/FINDNEXT is far much more faster then looping and searching for values in Excel Cells ;)

AND the below is even faster (*in fact the fastest*). You don't need to find the word if your final intention is to replace the word. Simply issue the **replace** command. If the code finds any word then it will automatically replace.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim ReplaceString As String

    '~~> Search String
    SearchString = "roadh"
    '~~> Replace string
    ReplaceString = UCase(SearchString)

    '~~> Replace the range below with the respective range
    Range("A1:A1000").Replace What:=SearchString, Replacement:=ReplaceString, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

You don't need to use the wildcard character to check for the presence of a string inside a string. **xlPart** in "*LookAt:=xlPart*" takes care of that :)

**FOLLOWUP** (In Case the user meant this)

> > > You may be missing the point here... OP is not only looking for roadh but for any road? where ? is a letter a-z. You have to figure out what ? is and make it uppercase. That's the (mildly) interesting twist of this problem. – Jean-François Corbett 1 hour ago

**Also checking for the scenario where the cell can contain multiple "road" values (as shown in snapshot below which has a 'before' and 'after' snapshot.**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set oRange = ws.Columns(1)

    SearchString = "road"

    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString & "?", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell

        FoundAt = aCell.Address

        aCell.Value = repl(aCell.Value, SearchString)

        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do

                FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address

                aCell.Value = repl(aCell.Value, SearchString)
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop

        MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt & " and replaced by UPPERCASE"

    Else
        MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"
    End If

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub

Function repl(cellValue As String, srchString As String) As String
    Dim pos As Integer

    pos = InStr(1, cellValue, srchString, vbTextCompare)
    repl = cellValue
    Do While pos <> 0
        If pos = 1 Then
            repl = UCase(Left(repl, Len(srchString) + 1)) & Mid(repl, Len(srchString) + 2)
        Else
            repl = Mid(repl, 1, pos - 1) & UCase(Mid(repl, pos, Len(srchString) + 1)) & _
            Mid(repl, pos + Len(srchString) + 1)
        End If
        Debug.Print repl

        pos = InStr(pos + 1, repl, srchString, vbTextCompare)
    Loop
End Function
```

**Snapshot**:

[image]

HTH

Sid

Comment: You may be missing the point here... OP is not only looking for `roadh` but for any `road?` where `?` is a letter `a-z`. You have to figure out what `?` is and make it uppercase. That's the (mildly) interesting twist of this problem.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: You could be right JCM :). I re-read the question and the question no way means what you just implied. Or am I missing seeing something which you can? This is what the author says "Cell A1 consists of "roadhouse blues". I want only 'roadh' to change to Uppercase if it exists in that cell."

Comment: Well, not to be cheeky, but read again: the OP says **Example:** Cell A1 consists of "roadhouse blues". The "`roadh` in `roadhouse blues`" thing is *only an example* and is not representative of what the OP wants *in general*. Look at what is written before the example. The code snippet clearly shows that the OP is not just looking for `roadh` (this is also implied in the comments to the question). Granted, the OP isn't very clear about any of this.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: Hmmm, I see what you are inferring to. Adding extra code to take that into consideration as well. Also adding and extra check (what if the cell has "roadhouse blues roadrent")?

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett: You didn't have to. But thanks for being kind :)

Comment: Full points for effort but I have to say it looks a bit long winded Sidd, have a look at the solution by Jindon crossposted at [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=162814)

Comment: @Reafidy: God I hate crossposting! Imagine the efforts put in by so many experts going down the drain. Yes you are right. That is a neat way to solve this problem. Also I would like to say that initially I was under the impression that the user just wanted to search and replace. It was only after JFC mentioned (see above) what the user actually wanted I came up with the followup code which as you rightly say is "a bit long winded" as compared to Jindon's code. :)

Comment: Yes I know what you mean with both comments!  The find/replace method would be so much more useful if there were more wild card options available!

Answer (score 2):

A way with a regexp, replaces all Road* in the input.

```
Sub repl(value As String)
    Dim re As Object: Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Dim matches As Object, i As Long
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = "(road[A-Z])"
    Set matches = re.Execute(value)
    For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        value = Replace$(value, matches(i), UCase$(matches(i)))
    Next
    Debug.Print value
End Sub
```